# Failed to verify code signature AFDateHelper

Tags: ios, cocoapods, hockeyapp

Using Cocoapods, I try to install an iOS app on my iPad with HockeyApp before releasing to the public. I get the following error:

> [ApplicationWorkspace]: Failed to install application: com.abc.def;
>   /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-1234/-5678; Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620415,
>   ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>   /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gu6tZL/extracted/Payload/MyProject.app/Frameworks/AFDateHelper.framework
>   : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}

That specific AFDateHelper Pod is not embedded nor linked in my target. Only the Pods_MyProject.framework is linked.

I have noticed that if I install all my Pods as Embedded Library it starts to work, but I get some errors on older iPad with incorrect architecture bugs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be embedded by the CocoaPods embed framework script.You can find a related CocoaPods issue and discussion at: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4331

Regards,
Fangfang